# Replace 4th occurrence of regex in line

Tags: command-line, text-processing

This is the output I have now. How can I get from Input to Output?

Input:

```
1.2.3.4.5
2.3.4.5.6
```

Output:

```
1.2.3.4-5
2.3.4.5-6
```

---

Bonus: I have the other 80% of the script done but this is my ideal output. Is there a super simple way to do it?

Input:

```
1.2.3.4-1.2.3.10
```

Output:

```
1.2.3.4-10
```

Comment: Bonus part is entirely separate case, so should belong in a separate question

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F '[-.]' '{printf "%s.%s.%s.%s-%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $NF}'
```

Since it looks like you want fields 1-4 and the last field from input separated by either `.` or `-`, and the output formatted with all but the last field separated by `.`.

More concisely:

```
awk -F '[-.]' -v OFS=. '{$4 = $4"-"$NF; NF=4}1'
```

- Add the last field to the fourth field and set the number of fields to 4.

Answer (score 0):

We can use grouping with  greedy match with sed like so:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*)\.(.*)$/\1-\2/' input.txt                                
1.2.3.4-5
2.3.4.5-6
```

Same idea for perl:

```
$ perl -pe's/(.*)\.(.*)$/\1-\2/' input.txt                               
1.2.3.4-5
2.3.4.5-6
```

But we can play around with `.` as column separator in awk:

```
$ awk -F '.' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{$NF=-$NF;sub(/\.-/,"-");print}' input.txt        
1.2.3.4-5
2.3.4.5-6
```

Answer (score 0):

First part:

```
$ sed 's/\./-/4' file.txt
```

Which replaces the 4th occurrence of `.` with a `-`.

---

For your Bonus section:

```
sed -r 's/(.*)-.*\.(.*)$/\1-\2/' file.txt
```

input:

```
1.2.3.4-1.2.3.10
```

output:

```
1.2.3.4-10
```